# What is the North American variant of a tower block?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, american-english

What is the American variant for a "tower block". A "tower block" may contain both residential apartments and offices in the same building. I have heard the terms like "apartment buildings", residential buildings", "apartment towers", "residential towers", "apartment blocks". But I think they all refer to buildings that contain only residential apartments and provide no space for commercial activities, correct me if I am wrong.

Let me tell you in Pakistan "commercial plaza" is a more common term for buildings that are used exclusively for business or commercial activities and not for residential purpose. Okay, let's just get back to the main topic I am looking for the exact term used in North America for a such a building that provide space for both residential and commercial purposes just as "tower block" a term used in British English.

Some people suggest "Skyscraper" is more common in the US but Skyscraper is a building with more than 50 floors and there could be buildings with less than 50 floors that offer space for both residential and commercial purposes at the same time in the same building. I am looking for what these buildings are called in the USA and Canada.

Comment: Would the Trump Tower be close to your idea of "tower block"? Trump Tower is a 58-story, 664-foot-high (202 m) ***mixed-use skyscraper***. Despite being located in one of Midtown Manhattan's special zoning districts, the tower was approved because ***it was built as a mixed-use development***. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_Tower

Comment: Interesting that *plaza* refers to a building. Is that right? I've only seen it refer to the city square around which such buildings are placed.

Comment: Yes, in Pakistan we have "commercial plazas" either short, mid-sized, or tall buildings with shops, offices for business and commercial activities and we also have "residential plazas", we also call them "residential towers" in Pakistan that are made up of apartments where people live with no offices and shops are located in them. And there are also such plazas or towers that offer both commercial activities and residential space.

Comment: Yeah Josh Trump Tower in Manhattan is a skyscraper having 58 floors. I already know about that. So does it mean that you call such buildings "towers" in the US. just towers?

Comment: Actually, "skyscraper" was first used on buildings much shorter than 50 floors.  It's all relative.

Comment: There's something similar in Italy, old *palazzi* (blocks/buildings) whose apartments have been converted into offices and private surgeries, the shops, if there are any, are always on the ground level. In Italian they just called *palazzo/i* (tall buildings/tower blocks/apartment buildings) A building is just a building. I suppose "multifunction (office) buildings" might be closer to the meaning you're seeking.

Comment: In the US, Peter Shor's suggestion of "high-rise" might be the most common term.  It's also often referred to simply as a "tower".

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the name in AmE for a tall building that's not necessarily as tall as a skyscraper, and can be either residential or commercial or both, try *high-rise*.

[American Heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=high-rise)
defines *high-rise* as "a tall building that is equipped with elevators and usually has at least six stories."

If you want a single word meaning a *mixed-use high-rise*, I don't know whether there is one.

Comment: What about *multifunction block/tower/building* does that term exists? I don't have time to do any research.

Comment: We don't generally call tall buildings *blocks* or *towers* here. But I'm not sure about whether *mixed-use* or *multifunction* is more common for this sense.

Comment: Yep, I was just coming back to suggest "high-rise".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for, anyway the following extract may be of help:

> ***[Mixed-use development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-use_development)*** is a type of urban development that ***blends residential, commercial, cultural, institutional, or industrial uses***, where those functions are physically and functionally integrated, and that provides pedestrian connections.
>
> ***Mixed-use development can take the form of a single building, a city block, or entire neighbourhoods***. The term may also be used more specifically to refer to a mixed-use real estate development project—a building, complex of buildings, or district of a town or city that is developed for mixed-use by a private developer, (quasi-) governmental agency, or a combination thereof.

(Wikipedia)

[image] From: dreamandhustle.com

Comment: @Mari-LouA - apparently the mixed-use definition is relatively common.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mixed-use+development%2Cmultifunction+development%2Cmultipurpose+development&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmixed%20-%20use%20development%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultipurpose%20development%3B%2Cc0